# How to retrieve sqlite database file on all devices?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, jakarta-mail

I have an app where I get the SQLite db file and send it through email. The thing is, that on some devices the filePath I retrieve with
`Context.getDatabasePath(“dbname.db”).getPath()`
returns null.

Do I need any special permissions for specific devices? Or is there another way a can retrieve the database file path that will work on all devices.

This is the code I use to get the file and send it:

```
public synchronized void sendDBMail(String subject, String body,
                                    String sender, String recipients, final DBSender.OnCompletionListener onCompletionListener) throws Throwable {

    // Create a default MimeMessage object.
    final Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

    // Set From: header field of the header.
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));

    // Set To: header field of the header.
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));

    // Set Subject: header field
    message.setSubject(subject);

    // Create the message part
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    // Now set the actual message
    messageBodyPart.setText(body);

    // Create a multipar message
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // Set text message part
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // Part two is attachment
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    File myDB = FileUtils.copyDBToSD(App.getContext(),BACKUP_DATABASES_DIR, DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
    String filePath = myDB.getPath();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filePath);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // Send the complete message parts
    message.setContent(multipart);

    // Send message
    Transport.send(message);
}

public static File copyDBToSD(Context ctx, String sdCardPath, String dataBaseFileName) throws Throwable {
    File dataBaseFile =  ctx.getDatabasePath(dataBaseFileName);
    File dataBaseCopy = FileUtils.createOrReadFileInSDCard(ctx,sdCardPath,dataBaseFileName);
    return copyFile(dataBaseFile, dataBaseCopy);
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "on some devices the filePath I retrieve with Context.getDatabasePath(“dbname.db”).getPath() returns null" -- what devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amend your `DBHelper` to :-

1) Include a class variable:-

```
    private static String DBPATH;
```

2) In the constructor after the super call add (assuming context is the variable name of the passed Context, otherwsie change accordingly):-

```
    DBPATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
```

3) Add a method:-

```
    public static String getDBPath() {
        return DBPATH;
    }
```

4) Then use :-

```
    File dataBaseFile =  new File(DBhelper.getDBPath());
```

Instead of

```
    File dataBaseFile =  ctx.getDatabasePath(dataBaseFileName);
```

You can then do away having the Context within `copyDBToSD`'s signature.

This, of course does rely upon an instance of `DBhelper` having been instantiated. It also assumes that the issue is based upon `App.getContext()` being the cause of the issue(s).

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my old app:

```
    private boolean expdb() {

            //exporting database file
            try {
                String filename = ("database_backup_" + DbOpenHelper.DB_NAME);
                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/yourAppName");
                //create directory if not exist
                if (!directory.isDirectory()) {
                    directory.mkdirs();
                }


                File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

                if (directory.canWrite()) {
                    String currentDBPath = "//data//" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "//databases//" + DbOpenHelper.DB_NAME;

                    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                    File backupDB = new File(directory, filename);

                    if (currentDB.exists()) {
                        FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                        FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                        src.close();
                        dst.close();
                    } else{
return false;}
                } else {
return false;}
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```